# Java: MouseListeners and returning objects

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener, acm-java-libraries

So I got this simple MouseListener set up. and I want it to get me which object I am pointing at. But it don´t seem´t work on GObjects, which are part of the acm library and included GRects, GLabels etc... it only returns to me the GCanvas itself (which is the canvas the objects are 'drawn' on). Anyone have a idea why this is?

```
public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e){
        println (e.getComponent());}
```

Comment: Probably because the mouse listener is context sensitive. If you attached the listener to the canvas, and no other components above it consume the event, it wills be passed to the container, cause that's where the event dispatching thinks the event occurred

Answer (score 1):

A [`GCanvas`](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GCanvas.html) extends [`Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) to which a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) can be attached.

[`GObject`](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GObject.html) OTOH extends [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), and cannot inherently have a `MouseListener` attached.

(The bounds of a shape drawn on-screen is not a 'component' as recognized by a mouse listener.)